# LÖVE crashes, when using a function in ipairs()

Tags: function, lua, lua-table

I was running an experiment on whether or not I am able to use autogenerating seeds in LÖVE, but I'm running into a problem. It crashes, when I try to add tiles into the game through a table using `ipairs`.
Can anybody see the problem with this code?:

```
    world = {}

function world.generate()
        for i = 1, 100 do
                world.addTile(i, love.math.random(1, 3), 1)
        end
        local tempWorld = world
        for i,v in ipairs(tempWorld) do
                world.addTile(v.x, v.y+1, 1)
        end
end

function world.addTile(x, y, id)
        for i,v in ipairs(tile) do
                if v.id == id then
                        table.insert(world, {id = id, x = x*tile.w, y = y*tile.h})
                else
                        print("The following id was not recognised: "..id)
                end
        end
end

function world.draw()
        for i,v in ipairs(world) do
                love.graphics.draw(tile.getImage(v.id), v.x, v.y)
        end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop.

`local tempWorld = world` does not copy `world`, it just creates another reference to it. So when `world` has another item added by `world.addTile` the for loop:

```
for i,v in ipairs(tempWorld) do
   world.addTile(v.x, v.y+1, 1)
end
```

has a new stopping point since `ipairs` has one more item to iterate. This repeats until you run out of memory. You may want to save the size of the old list instead:

```
local oldsize = #world
for i=1, oldsize do
   local v = world[i]
   world.addTile(v.x, v.y+1, 1)
end
```

And now it wont iterate more than `oldsize` times.

Comment: Ah, I was not knowing that! Thanks! That really clarified it :) Happy programming!